# Route planning in gwt

Tags: api, gwt, routes

Is there a way to display a map like google-maps in my gwt-application.

I want to implement a page with that the user can plan a route to 2-4 different designation.

Or something to get the distance from point A to point B.

Can you give me some examples and tips.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/detail?id=381#c53

In its current state, there's no `Widget`, but you could use a `SimplePanel` in the mean time:

```java
SimplePanel mapWidget = new SimplePanel();
// add the widget to a parent widget, then:
GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(mapWidget.getElement());
```

or if you use UiBinder:

```java
<div ui:field='mapElement'></div>
```

```java
@UiField DivElement mapElement;

...

GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(mapElement);
```

You can then use the [`DirectionsService`](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svntrunk/javadoc/maps/3.8/com/google/maps/gwt/client/DirectionsService.html) to get directions, and the [`com.google.maps.gwt.client.geometry` package](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svntrunk/javadoc/maps/3.8/com/google/maps/gwt/client/geometry/Spherical.html#computeDistanceBetween%28com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng,%20com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng%29) to compute distances between points.

The API being automatically generated from JavaScript, it should be similar enough that you'll be able to easily adapt JS examples you find on the web to the GWT bindings.